# scikit-learn refit/partial fit option in Classifers

Tags: machine-learning, parameters, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am wondering is there any option in sklearn classifiers to fit using some hyperparameters and after changing a few hyperparameter(s), refit the model by saving computation (fit) cost.

Let us say, Logistic Regression is fit using `C=1e5` (`logreg=linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e5)`) and we change only `C` to `C=1e3`. I want to save some computation because only one parameter is changed.

Comment: As far as I know, bayesian hyperparameter optimization is the fastest method: https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization. You can create a new question for this, maybe people will have better ideas.

Comment: Bayesian hyperparameter optimization often has the problem that it has more hyperparameters than the model you're trying to tune. Here is an interesting alternative: http://blog.dlib.net/2017/12/a-global-optimization-algorithm-worth.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is a technique called `warm_start` which, citing from the documentation, means:

> **warm_start** : bool, default: False 
>   
>  When set to True, reuse the solution of the previous call to fit as initialization, otherwise,
>   just erase the previous solution. Useless for liblinear solver.

As described in the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression), it's available in `LogisticRegression` :

```
sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression(..., warm_start=False, n_jobs=1)
```

So concretely, for your case you would do the following:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 

# create an instance of LogisticRegression with warm_start=True
logreg = LogisticRegression(C=1e5, warm_start=True)
# you can access the C parameter's value as follows
logreg.C 
# it's set to 100000.0

# .... 
# train your model here by calling logreg.fit(..)
# ....

# reset the value of the C parameter as follows 
logreg.C = 1e3 

logreg.C 
# now it's set to 1000.0

# .... 
# re-train your model here by calling logreg.fit(..)
# ....
```

As far as I have been able to check quickly, it's available also in the following:

- [sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)
- [sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html)
- [sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier.html)
- [sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html)
- [sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I am experimenting to search best parameters (as an alternative to Grid Search in sklearn). Theoretical, my stance is that if we change only a single parameter and `fit` the model again, it should take less time than the first time (if `warm_start=True`), but empirically it is not true. Can you please help?

Comment: @Nawaz I've just commented on your question.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that.